# ¿Cómo se haría esta sentencia curl en Python usando requests?

Tags: python, http, curl

Cómo se hace esta sentencia:

```
curl -v -u {email_address}:{password} -X PUT -H "Content-Type: 
application/json" \
  -d '{"user": {"remote_photo_url": 
"http://link.to/profile/image.png"}}' \
  https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/{id}.json
```

en Python usando requests? Tengo esto:

```
url="https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/{id}.json"
payload=json.dumps({"user": {"remote_photo_url":"http://link.to/profile/image.png"}})
r = requests.put(url, auth=(creds['user'], creds['password']), data=payload)
```

Y si imprimo r.status_code recibo un 200, pero al hacer r.content aparece como que el contenido no se ha modificado. Y no sé si esta bien hecho el código o es cosa del servidor.

Comment: ¿Ya está solucionado el problema? Este no es un foro, no existe la marca `[EDIT]`. Puedes publicar __y aceptar__ tu respuesta o borrar tu pregunta. La tercera alternativa es que votar para cerrarla, porque el problema es un error tipográfico o similar.

Comment: Entiendo, lo siento no sabía cómo poner para decir la solución que a mi problema, sin borrar la pregunta. Entonces debería, cerrar la pregunta?

Comment: Yo te recomiendo que publiques y aceptes la respuesta. Y de ser posible, que agregues una explicación del origen del error y como la solución evita la recurrencia. De este modo, tu problema puede ayudar a otros usuarios que presenten, en el futuro, un problema como el tuyo.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. :)

Answer (score 1):

En la sentencia curl, especifica de manera explícita el tipo de header que necesita el servidor, entonces lo único que hay que hacer al anterior código es agregarle dicha cabecera:

```
url="https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/{id}.json"
payload=json.dumps({"user": {"remote_photo_url":"http://link.to/profile/image.png"}})
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.put(url, auth=(creds['user'], creds['password']), headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Por esta razón no se modificaba ningún dato.